# How to get column names from HQL query&result to json with Key as columns

Tags: java, json, hql, gson

How to convert hql query result directly to Json.I tried this one

```
            Query query=session.createQuery(SQLUtilsConstants.fQuery);
    query.setParameter(StringConstants.TRPID, trId);
    List list=query.list();
            gson = new Gson();
            String jsonStudents = gson.toJson(list);
           System.out.println("jsonStudents = " + jsonStudents);
```

When i converted.I get a json with list of values without properties.Query result contains data from multiple table .I want to generate result with properties as key and value as output.If query contains customerid and customername then i need a result like this.

```
      [{"customerid" : "abc", "customername" : "rose"}]
```

But using above code i getting like this..
          [{"abc", "rose"}]

How can i do this???

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Map, how ever you want it. then parse the map into json.

> ```
> Map<String,WhatEver> newMap = new HashMap<String,WhatEver>();
> foreach(WhatEver item: list){
>       //create your map how ever you like it to be
> ```
>
> }
>   String jsonStudents = gson.toJson(newMap);

Comment: in my case,query is dynamically generated one.So i can' set properties as key when iterating.Each time prpoerties will be different.In above example how can i know result contain which all properties like customername,customerid:

Comment: how will the properties be different? you can get different classes from the same query?

Comment: i am confused.can anyone explain Hashmap logic with sample code.then it will be clear